# Where do I execute native SQL queries in Loopback 4?

Tags: sql, node.js, api, crud, loopback

I'm new to Loopback 4 and I've been trying to execute a native SQL query. I found how to do it, the thing is that don't have any clue of WHERE to put it in my code in order for it to work... here's the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Executing-database-commands.html) I found.

I need to know where should I put this:

```
const result = await repository.execute('SELECT * FROM Products');
```

in my Loopback project, which has many files. My goal is to make a REST endpoint like `/products/[name]` with `[name]` being a parameter inserted dynamically to the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would implement it as a new Repository method.

Let's say your model is called `Product`, then you should have `src/repositories/product.repository.ts` file exporting `ProductRepository` class already present in your project. (You can run `lb4 repository` to create it.)

```
export class Product extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Product,
  typeof Product,
  Product Relations
> {
  constructor(@inject('datasources.db') dataSource: DbDataSource) {
    super(Product, dataSource);
  }

  // your custom method
  async selectByName(name: string): Promise<Product[]> {
    const rawItems = await repository.execute('SELECT * FROM Products');
    // would you like to convert raw data into Product instances?
    return rawItems.map(it => new Product(it));
  }
}
```

Then you can call this new custom repository method from your controller in the same way as you would call e.g. `repository.find(filter)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've helped me a lot :)

Comment: @NicoHorn happy to help :) Could you please up-vote my answer if you find it useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in your controller class as per loopback docs https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controller.html. As you will define the REST endpoint in the controller itself you can also do the insertion there using repository.execute() e.g.

```
  @get('/products/{name}')
  async doSomething(    
    @param.path.string('name') name: string,
  ): Promise<Product> {
  
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field="${name}"`;
  await this.productRepository.execute(sql)
        
         --- other lines of code & return value --
  }
```